# Status changed directly from "Awaiting Reviewer Assignment" to "Awaiting Editor Recommendation"

Tags: paper-submission

I recently submitted my first paper to a bioinformatics journal. At first, the status changed as normal into "Awaiting Reviewer Assignment." However, After five days, the status switched from "Awaiting Reviewer Assignment" directly to "Awaiting Editor Recommendation."
Does that imply that the manuscript is not revised and will be rejected, or does it mean? Is this a bad sign or not?

Comment: It seems something standard. Next, hopefully, they should contact the referees.

Comment: It jumped over “awaiting reviewer scores” stage, so I am not sure whether manuscript is revised.

Comment: Nobody can know, and so the answer was closed. It may be that the reviewers already handed in their reviews, or it may mean something else. The only option you have is exercise patience and wait for the editor's report.